# Trying again using multiple loops in a code

Tags: python

I have a problem using the while loop. When I am inputting right answer for example, and the second one is wrong, the tryAgain input is showing. If I want to play again, it just looping in from the start and choosing a topic won't work. If I made it wrong, from the start, it will just loop on its own from inputting answers.

```
tryAgain = True
repeat = True
while tryAgain:
    print("TOPICS: \n")
    print("1. topic 1")
    print("2. topic 2")
    print("3. topic 3")
    print("======================================")
    num = int(input("PICK A NUMBER FOR THE TOPIC [1-3]: "))
    if num > 3:
        print("There is no given topic")
        print("==========================")
        tryAgain = True
    else:
        if num == 1: 
            reader = WordListCorpusReader('filename', ['textfile'])
            with open('filename') as f:
                text = [line.strip().upper() for line in f]
            answer = [] 
            while lives > 0:
                while repeat:
                    index = 0
                    while index < 10:
                        answerlst = input(str(index + 1) + '. ').upper()
                        if answerlst in text: #condition if the inputted answer is on the file
                            if answerlst in answer: #check if the inputted answer is on the array  
                                print("\nYou repeated your answer!")
                                repeat = True
                                continue
                            else:
                                answer.append(answerlst)
                                print("Correct!")
                                repeat = False
                                if answerlst == "ans1":
                                    print("Points: 10")
                                    points += 10
                                elif answerlst == "ans2":
                                    print("Points: 20")
                                    points += 20
                                elif answerlst == "ans3":
                                    print("Points: 30")
                                    points += 30
                                elif answerlst == "ans4":
                                    print("Points: 40")
                                    points += 40
                                elif answerlst == "ans5":
                                    print("Points: 50")
                                    points += 50
                                elif answerlst == "ans6":
                                    print("Points: 60")
                                    points += 60
                                elif answerlst == "ans7":
                                    print("Points: 70")
                                    points += 70
                                elif answerlst == "ans8":
                                    print("Points: 80")
                                    points += 80
                                elif answerlst == "ans9":
                                    print("Points: 90")
                                    points += 90
                                elif answerlst == "ans10":
                                    print("Points: 100")
                                    points += 100                       
                                if points == 550:
                                    print("\nCONGRATULATIONS!!!! YOU GOT A PERFECT POINTS OF:", points)
                                    break
                        else:
                            if answerlst == "ans1":
                                points += 10
                            elif answerlst == "ans2":
                                points += 20
                            elif answerlst == "ans":
                                points += 30
                            elif answerlst == "ans4":
                                points += 40
                            elif answerlst == "ans5":
                                points += 50
                            elif answerlst == "ans6": 
                                points += 60
                            elif answerlst == "ans7":
                                points += 70
                            elif answerlst == "ans8":
                                points += 80
                            elif answerlst == "ans9":
                                points += 90
                            elif answerlst == "ans10":
                                points += 100
                            lives -= 1
                            if lives == 0:
                                print("\nGAME OVER!!!!!\n")
                                print("You just got a: ", points)
                                break
                        index +=1

    playAgain = input("Do you want to play again? [Y] / [N]: ").upper()
    if playAgain == 'Y':
        answer.clear() #to clear the list
        tryAgain = True
```

I just show the structure of my code in order to understand.

Comment: You never set `tryAgain` to `False`, your loop won't ever finish

Comment: Where will I set the tryAgain = False?

Comment: I also having a problem if the inputted answer is wrong, the loop starting on its own when I have the break in else condition.

Comment: And even I get all the correct answers, the asking if the user wanna try again won't show up

Comment: You might want to use Python 3.10's structural pattern matching for this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/

Comment: @DSteman is my problem related to that?

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, because now you've learned what *spaghetti* code is - it's just a mess, where you can't properly find errors. When such situation occurs, try to divide your problem into smaller parts (stages). Implement the stages as functions, and your code will become much easier.

For example I tried to rework your program like this. **ATTENTION**: I don't have your files, so this code probably won't work out of the box, I cannot test it. But just try to read it and understand the approaches.

After reworking this code I noticed that you never set `lives` to any number, but you should.

```
def input_topic():
    while True:
        print("TOPICS: \n")
        print("1. topic 1")
        print("2. topic 2")
        print("3. topic 3")
        print("======================================")
        topic = int(input("PICK A NUMBER FOR THE TOPIC [1-3]: "))
        if topic > 3:
            print("There is no given topic")
            print("==========================")
        else:
            return topic        

def read_text(filename):
    reader = WordListCorpusReader(filename, ['textfile'])
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = [line.strip().upper() for line in f]
    return text

def input_answer_and_check(index, text, already_answered):
    while True:
        answerlst = input(str(index+1) + '. ').upper()
        if answerlst in text:
            if answerlst not in answer:
                return True, answerlst 
            else:
                print("\nYou repeated your answer!")
        else:
            return False, answerlst
                    
def get_answer_points(answerlst)
    if answerlst == "ans1":
        return 10
    elif answerlst == "ans2":
        return 20
    elif answerlst == "ans3":
        return 30
    elif answerlst == "ans4":
        return 40
    elif answerlst == "ans5":
        return 50
    elif answerlst == "ans6":
        return 60
    elif answerlst == "ans7":
        return 70
    elif answerlst == "ans8":
        return 80
    elif answerlst == "ans9":
        return 90
    elif answerlst == "ans10":
        return 100    

def ask_try_again():
    playAgain = input("Do you want to play again? [Y] / [N]: ").upper()
    return playAgain == 'Y'
        
while True:
    topic = input_topic()
    text = read_text('filename')
    answer = [] 
    lives_left = 5
    index = 0
    max_index = 10
    total_points = 0

    while lives_left > 0 and index < max_index and total_points < 550:
        is_correct_answer, answerlst = input_answer_and_check(index, text, answer)
        answer_points = get_answer_points(answerlst)
        total_points += answer_points
        if is_correct_answer:
            answer.append(answerlst)
            print("Correct!")
            print(f"Points: {answer_points}")
        else:
            lives_left -= 1
        index += 1

    if lives_left == 0:
        print("\nGAME OVER!!!!!\n")
        print("You just got a: ", total_points)
    elif total_points >= 550:
        print("\nCONGRATULATIONS!!!! YOU GOT A PERFECT POINTS OF:", total_points)
    
    if not ask_try_again():
        break
```

Comment: I tried the code but it says that the answelst is not defined. I am new using the def function so my code is a bit messy.

Comment: In my code, which is the problem?

Comment: And I setup my lives into 1. 1 wrong answer is already a game over. I just forgot to put it.

Comment: I changed my answer. I can't tell what's the problem in your code, because it's way to complicated to spot an error right away

Comment: I feel like I am having a problem about the breaking and indentation but yeah, it is hard to figured out. I am trying to fix my code 1 by 1 but when I try to insert all the loops and condition, the pattern is messed up

Comment: `def` is not that hard, you just pass something in parentheses, and it returns something back using `return` statement. The only trick I used in `input_answer_and_check` is to return two values from it, and when I call it, like that `is_correct_answer, aswerlst = input_answer_and_check(index, text, answer)`, `is_correct_answer` will contain the boolean value, and `aswerlst` the answer variant from this function

Comment: I still have the same error in your code where answerlst is not defined

Comment: @Jay Yeah, another typo by me